My Objects keep becoming deformed when I rotate the bones
Ive been working on this rig and have set up all of the weights seemingly correct, but everytime i rotate one of the bones, the associated object and its bone stretches and squashes without me being able to stop it
this is how it looks normally:

this is how it looks when i rotate the bones:

Its especially noticeable with the head (this is normal):

this is not (mind the lack of neck, that's for later):

any idea as to how this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks greatly.

It's hard to tell from the screenshots alone, but judging from how the bones seem to get skewed, it smells like non-uniform scaling.

In pose mode, select all bones with A ang go in the menu Pose > Clear Transform > All:

↹ Tab into object mode, select the mesh(es) object(s) and the armature, and press ⎈ CtrlA > Apply Scale. You might also want to apply the rotation too if they aren't.

